# Node.js Express execute inside app.post()

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a problem right now that I can't solve by myself. I assume you know more here. I'm just getting started.

By using the following code I'm getting a list of customers:

```
app.get("/customers", customers.findAll);
```

I wanted to add authentication. But now I don't know how to execute "customers.findAll" and get the value as JSON.

```
app.get("/customers", verifyToken, (req, res) => {
    jwt.verify(req.token, 'justAtest, (err, authData) => {
    if (err) {
     res.sendStatus(403);
    } else { 
      // execute customers.findAll
    }
   }); 
  });
```

Customers is integrated via a requirement

```
const customers = require("../controllers/customer.controller.js");
```

The contents are as follows:

```
exports.findAll = (req, res) => {
  Customer.getAll((err, data) => {
    if (err)
      res.status(500).send({
        message:
          err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving customers."
      });
    else res.send(data);
  });
};
```

Do you have any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Grettings

Rok

Comment: `} else { customers.findAll(req, res); }`

Comment: oh thats it.. im so stupid. I tried res.send(customers.findAll(req, res)); and it didn't work. :D Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You achieve that using something called "middleware". Explore it since it is very important.

Basically :

```
app.get("/customers", verifyToken,customers.findAll);
```

Wherre verify token is a funtion that has 3 parameters: req, res and 3rd one called "next".
So your verify token function would look something like:

```
(req, res,next) => {
    jwt.verify(req.token, 'justAtest, (err, authData) => {
    if (err) {
     res.sendStatus(403);
    } else { 
      next();
    }
   }); 
  }
```

I took it from your snippet. Basically if you want to jump to customeeers.finalAll, just call "next" and it jumps to next function :D.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But the comment below my question is working fine for me :) I'm sure this would have also solved my problem. Thank you

Comment: No problem, just keep in mind what would happen if you had multiple endpoints that need to verify token ? You would have duplicated code. That's one of the reasons middlewares exist ^^